# React Native ScrollView Animated

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native

I am having trouble when using ScrollView in React Native in conjunction with Animated. Hoping to see if anyone knew why this was happening, or a workaround solution!

Basically, I would like to have a page that has a toggle for switching the content that is shown. In this example I will provide, I will have a `Daily View` and a `Weekly View` that are each ScrollViews. The DailyView will show by default, and then I would like to basically press a button to toggle the views. The Daily View Scroll View will animate out of view (through opacity and translation-y) and the Weekly View Scroll View will animate in (through opacity and translation-y).

I have gotten the animation to work with the toggling...however, the ScrollViews for both are not working as they should. They allow me to think I am scrolling and then immediately when I let go, it bounces back to the top.

Here is a snack demonstrating: https://snack.expo.io/BkTrdN8RZ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `height` style for `ScrollView` parent.

I've checked - It will fix an issue with scrolling.
However i cannot explain why it happening.

```js
     <View style={{
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height
      }}> 
        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>This is the Text for Weekly View</Text>
          <Text>{lipsum}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```